# Agregar texto detrás de un echo

Tags: php, html, mysql

¿Cómo puedo insertar un `<input type="text">` detrás de un `echo`?

```
while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
        echo $row ['rut'].'<br>';
        echo $row ['nroPiloto'].'<br>';
        echo $row ['nombre'].'<br>';
        echo $row ['fono'].'<br>';
        echo $row ['correo'].'<br>';
        
    }
```

Arroja datos tipos así:

```sh
4494949494-4
7
Mario Hugo
33333333
mario@gmail.com
```

pero yo quiero que aparezca así:

```sh
rut :4494949494-4
numero :7
nombre :Mario Hugo
telefono :33333333
correo :mario@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Concatenar el texto deseado es lo que necesitas

```
while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
        echo "Rut: ".$row ['rut'].'<br>';
        echo "Numero: ".$row ['nroPiloto'].'<br>';
        echo "Nombre: ".$row ['nombre'].'<br>';
        echo "Telefono: ".$row ['fono'].'<br>';
        echo "Correo: ".$row ['correo'].'<br>';
        
    }
```

Comment: @Sebastian concatenar es lo que necesitas

Comment: Hola @pperez lo hice la siguiente manera :                                              `            `while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
                echo 'DATOS DEL PILOTO:'.'<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo 'RUT: ';
                echo $row ['rut'].'<br>';
                echo 'Numero de Piloto: ';
                echo $row ['nroPiloto'].'<br>';
                echo 'Nombre: ';
                echo $row ['nombre'].'<br>';...`

Comment: Muchas gracias !

Comment: @Sebastian Los agradecimientos estan muy bien, pero aquí los mostramos aceptando las respuestas válidas. Haz el [tour] para aprender bien el funcionamiento del sitio, y mira [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando una respuesta es válida.  Si no lo haces dejarás la pregunta sin responder eternamente y los que vengan detrás no sabran si te ha servido o no. Gracias.